# Can you use '<<: *default' in secrets.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `database.yml` you can have a default environment and have the other inherit:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dev_development

test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: test_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: test_production
```

**Can you do this in secrets.yml? Should you?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's just the format; you can use it in any YML file.

Comment: The document here doesn't say anything about the `<<:` command to include the default set, so thank you for this question and answer. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html#label-Support+for+YAML+defaults